# CORS Error on Uno WebAssembly with ASP..NET Core REST API Service

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, uwp, xmlhttprequest, uno-platform

I got these error on WebAssembly with Uno Platform.

> Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44318/api/search/bebek/TR' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:49917' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I got some data responses as a JSON file from API service. The UWP app do it without error:

```
 //_savedSearchList = await _dbService.SearchAsync(_keyword, _sentLanguageArgument);  // Normal database connection for UWP.

                //_savedSearchList = await _dbService.SearchAsync(_keyword, _sentLanguageArgument);  // Normal database connection for UWP.

                //Get search list for webservice.
                var link_search = $"https://localhost:44318/api/search/{_keyword.ToLower()}/{_sentLanguageArgument}";



                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(link_search);
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Http Status Code for Connection: {response.StatusCode}");
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        _savedSearchList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SearchResultCapsule>>(jsonString).OrderBy(t => t.IssueNumber);



                        if (_savedSearchList.Count() != 0)
                        {

                            ResultList.ItemsSource = _savedSearchList;
                            NoResult_Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

What is the real problem on WebAssembly ? And how can I fix it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security restriction from the Javascript `fetch` API, where the endpoint you're calling needs to provide [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to work properly.

If you control the API, you'll need to use the features from your framework to enable CORS, and if you don't you'll need to ask the maintainers of the endpoint to enable CORS.

To test if CORS is really the issue, you can use [CORS Anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) to proxy the queries.

Answer (score -2):

It solved via Microsoft CORS package. Thanks.